# How to make an installed python module usable for another user?

Tags: bash, permissions, python, php

I'm running a bash script with php which will in turn run a python script but I get so many errors because it seems like `www-data` can't use the python packages I have installed for my own user. So how can I make a specific package available for `www-data` is it safe to do that? also is it safe to set `www-data` as the owner of a specific subtree of `/var/www/html`?

Here is the error I get when I run the following command:

```
sudo -u www-data ./bash_script_that_calls_runs_the_pythonscript.sh

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./file.py", line 5, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
ImportError: No module named 'bs4'
```

But if I run:

```
./bash_script_that_calls_runs_the_pythonscript.sh
```

Everything will go fine.

And also:

```
~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages$ ll | grep bs4
drwxrwxr-x  5 me www-data  4096 Dec  2 15:37 bs4/
drwxrwxr-x  2 me www-data  4096 Dec  2 15:38 bs4-0.0.1.dist-info/
```

Please note that I've set the group recursively:

```
$ ll /home/me/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/bs4/
total 180
drwxrwxr-x  5 me www-data  4096 Dec  2 15:37 ./
drwx------ 51 me me        4096 Jan 16 04:33 ../
drwxrwxr-x  3 me www-data  4096 Dec  2 15:37 builder/
-rw-rw-r--  1 me www-data 29910 Dec  2 15:38 dammit.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 me www-data  6773 Dec  2 15:38 diagnose.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 me www-data 68798 Dec  2 15:38 element.py
-rw-rw-r--  1 me www-data 20394 Dec  2 15:38 __init__.py
drwxrwxr-x  2 me www-data  4096 Dec  2 15:37 __pycache__/
-rw-rw-r--  1 me www-data 30800 Dec  2 15:38 testing.py
drwxrwxr-x  3 me www-data  4096 Dec  2 15:37 tests/
```

The same goes for `bs4-0.0.1.dist-info/`

Comment: Does www-data have execute permissions for the Python module?

Comment: @WJAndrea I think so(see the edit)

Comment: For a module in a directory, I think you need execute permissions for the `__init__.py` file. You might need execute permissions for all other .py files in the directory too.

Comment: @WJAndrea the permissions for the user and group seem to be the same. to I have to reload anything after changing the permissions to make changes take effect?

Answer (score 1):

**Answer:**

Add `-H` or `-i` option to `sudo`:

```
sudo -i -u www-data ./bash_script_that_calls_runs_the_pythonscript.sh
sudo -H -u www-data ./bash_script_that_calls_runs_the_pythonscript.sh
```

**Explain:**

You can use `python -m site` to check importing paths. For example, in the outputs of `sudo -u www-data python -m site`, `USER_SITE` is not the expected directory `bs4` installed.

```
sys.path = [
    '/',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6.2/lib/python36.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6.2/lib/python3.6',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6.2/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/root/.local' (doesn't exist)
USER_SITE: '/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (doesn't exist)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

With `sudo -i` or `sudo -H`, you can switch home directory to user `www-data` and find the correct `USER_SITE`. The outputs of `sudo -i -u www-data python -m site` may be:

```
sys.path = [
    '/home/www-data',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6.2/lib/python36.zip',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6.2/lib/python3.6',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6.2/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',
    '/home/www-data/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
    '/usr/local/lib/python3.6.2/lib/python3.6/site-packages',
]
USER_BASE: '/home/www-data/.local' (exists)
USER_SITE: '/home/www-data/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages' (exists)
ENABLE_USER_SITE: True
```

Comment: I don't want to run it from commandline! I want to run is from within a php script that is run by a request from the user.

Comment: When php received a request, can you print the outputs of `python -m site` in `bash_script_that_calls_runs_the_pythonscript.sh`?